# swiper not getting installed

Tags: node.js, swiper.js

I am trying to install npm i swiper@5.3.0 but I get error 522 . I am using npm version 6.5.0

````
npm ERR! path C:\Users\<user>\demo-swiper\node_modules\swiper
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp\postinstall-537039b0.cmd
npm ERR! "Love Swiper? Support Vladimir's work by donating or pledging on patreon:
npm ERR! The syntax of the command is incorrect.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-03-03T12_23_23_845Z-debug-0.log```

As I am using it other project which needed npm v6.5.0, I thought maybe project had issue but when I installed in stand alone. it does not work.
````

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, swiper@5.3.0 would not work with version of npm version 6.5.0. The solution is to install Node version manager. after that run you want to check which version you are using on npm, by running

```
nvm -v
```

and if you are on 6.5.0 then u need something greater than that, to check which version are available by running the following

```
nvm list
```

then use `nvm use <version>` this will switch to that  number.

Now install the `swiper@5.3.0`, once it has been done then switch back to old version on npm.